# If my data is overdispersed when binomial but not when Poisson does that alone mean I should use Poisson GLM?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, binomial-distribution, poisson-distribution, quasi-likelihood

Top is Poisson, bottom is Binomial

Source of variation is different people observed over a week long period. 118 people to be exact.

- want to make predictions about the proportion of days/week one exercises if they wake up at a given time.

```
> summary(FMR7)

Call:
glm(formula = No.Days.Ex ~ WaketimeStand, family = poisson, data = PSD)

Deviance Residuals: 
     Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
-2.99043  -0.64677  -0.03492   0.67393   1.51943  

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)    1.36991    0.04689  29.218   <2e-16 ***
WaketimeStand -0.08309    0.04806  -1.729   0.0839 .  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 124.55  on 115  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 121.51  on 114  degrees of freedom
AIC: 479.71

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4

> summary(FMR6)

Call:
glm(formula = cbind(No.Days.Ex, No.Days.NotEx) ~ WaketimeStand, 
    family = quasibinomial(link = logit), data = PSD)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-3.7483  -0.9585  -0.0625   1.0428   2.9739  

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)     0.2595     0.1009   2.571   0.0114 *
WaketimeStand  -0.1869     0.1020  -1.832   0.0695 .
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for quasibinomial family taken to be 2.015388)

    Null deviance: 288.42  on 115  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 281.57  on 114  degrees of freedom
AIC: NA

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```

Quite clear that there is much more overdispersion on the quasibinomial than the poisson. The response variable is no.days exercise per week and so my original thought was to analyse with binomial GLM as it is the proportion of days in a week someone exercises. However, when modelled with a Poisson GLM it is much less overdispersed. Is this a sign I am using the wrong distribution.

Comment: Also, my Poisson has a lower AIC than Binomial, does this mean I should use poisson?